# express 3.0 how to use app.locals.use and res.locals.use

Tags: node.js, express

I am on express3.0rc2. How to use `app.locals.use`(does it still exist) and `res.locals.use`

I saw this https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1131 but app.locals.use throws an error. I am assuming that once I put the function in app.locals.use I can use it in the routes.

I was thinking of adding

```
app.locals.use(myMiddleware(req,res,next){res.locals.uname = 'fresh'; next();})
```

and then in any route call this middleware

thanks

Answer (score 11):

I'm using Express 3.0 and this works for me:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.myVar = 'myVal';
  res.locals.myOtherVar = 'myOtherVal';
  next();
});
```

I then have access to `myVal` and `myOtherVal` in my templates (or directly via `res.locals`).

Comment: i understand res.locals but whats up with the res.locals.use..??

Comment: `res.locals` is simply used to pass values to a template. `res.locals.use` is undefined unless you assign it. Look at https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L708

Comment: I was a tad confused by the statement "I then have access to **myVal** and **myOtherVal**" because I thought it meant you could just do something like `myVar += 'anotherString'`, but really you still would have to have the **res.locals.** part i.e. `res.locals.myVar += 'anotherString'` . then it will work

Answer (score 9):

If I understand you correctly you can do the following:

```
app.configure(function(){
  // default express config
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.custom = "some content";
    next();
  })
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.custom)
});
```

You can now use the req.custom variable in every route. Make sure you put the app.use function before the router!

Edit:

ok next try :) you can either use your middleware and specify it in the routes you want:

```
function myMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.uname = 'fresh';
    next();
}

app.get("/", myMiddleware, function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.custom)
});
```

or you can set it "globally":

```
app.locals.uname = 'fresh';

// which is short for

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.uname = "fresh";
  next();
});
```

Comment: no I want to call function across different routes and I am assuming app.locals would help me do that

Comment: thanks. but if you checked the github link I sent has the myMiddleware being defined and then a call to app.locals.use(myMiddleware) from now on route function is able to call myMiddleware. but I am not able to do that since app.locals.use throws an error. and what is the concept with res.locals.use(i understand res.locals)..thanks again

Comment: so how am i going to access uname in my templates?

Comment: A little late, but if you define `app.locals.uname = 'fresh'` you should be able to access it within any template as only `uname`.